# Kv file outputs different results from calling it into native python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I print in the build function of the app `root.size` and get the ouptut `(100,100)` which is default to any widget, but if I try to create a button in the .kv file that when is pressed prints `root.size` prints `(800,600)` Why is that happening?

```
class MovieApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = MovieScreen()
        print(root.size)
        return MovieScreen()
MovieApp().run()
```

movie.kv

```
<MovieScreen>
    Button:
        on_press: print(root.size)
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        background_color: 1,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because during the build method `root.size` has value `(100, 100)`, but once the app is running `root.size` has value `(800, 600)`, presumably because the layout logic has now run and it is filling the default-sized Window.